# Apache Camel aggregate persistence and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, serialization, apache-camel

A get messages from JPA endpoint (using Hibernate as a persistence provider). Then I aggregate these messages for batch processing. Everyting works fine until I need to restart my application. In this case Camel tries to recover messages for aggregate, and it uses Java serialization to store/retrieve messages to/from LevelDB. The problem is that incoming messages are Hibernate entities, and they seem to store references to Hibernate internals. It causes the following error when trying to deserialize these message during recovery:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=4660e351-5c08-4dfe-887f-f03a475582ae,name=null]
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateSessionFactoryOnDeserialization(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1781)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.deserialize(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1811)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.readObject(SessionImpl.java:2189)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
  at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
```

**UPD**: here are excerpts from my configuration:

```
<endpoint id="repository-schedule-day-group" uri="jpa:my.pkg.InputScheduleDayGroup?consumeDelete=false&amp;consumer.namedQuery=changedScheduleDayGroups&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1000&amp;consumer.delay=500"/>

<route id="repository-schedule-day-group-route">
  <from ref="repository-schedule-day-group"/>
  <aggregate strategyRef="listAggregator" completionSize="100" completionTimeout="5000"
      aggregationRepositoryRef="persister.dayGroup">
    <correlationExpression>
      <constant>true</constant>
    </correlationExpression>
    <bean ref="portal.scheduleDaysMapper"/>
    <setHeader headerName="ws.path">
      <simple>workingtime/schedules</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <to ref="portal-ws-post"/>
  </aggregate>
</route>
```

I do aggregation since `portal.scheduleDaysMapper` works much faster with batch of entities than with multiple entities independently. Also, `portal-ws-post` is a REST endpoint, that of course has severe overhead with thousands of small messages.

Answer (score 0):

I've found workaround. I added the following line before aggregate:

```
  <removeHeader headerName="CamelEntityManager"/>
```

Shame on Apache Camel it can't even handle such simple cases out of the box without such dirty hacks.

Comment: Well to help Camel why not post your route configuration so people have a chance to figure out how to help you and also how to solve this out of the box.

Comment: I've altered my original answer and added configuration, as you said. Hope it helps.